# How secure is it to use Tor on an outdated OSX

Tags: security, mac

Hi :) I'm unable to update my OSX and it needs to be updated.
Does the fact that my OSX is outdated make TOR less secure to use?

Answer (score 0):

It makes your computer as a whole less secure because new security issues will not be patched.

Tor Browser will work the same as it always did but it won't change that fact that your machine is more vulnerable.

Comment: # JS Evans: Thanks for the reply! So while the computer is less secured in general, TOR itself is as safe as on an updated OS ?

Answer (score 0):

Tor is only as secure as your OS is. That's why Windows users of Tor are usually targets for hacking. Windows is not as secure as linux or MacOS and thus is more vulnerable.

Since your OSX is outdated, you are more vulnerable to hacking since newer security patches haven't been added. Everytime your OS is updated, new bugs are patched and issues are resolved. Tor will have all its security patches to protect you, but if your system has security holes, then you are still susceptible to malware and hacking.